# How to find the source code of the class OpenHashMapBasedStateMap in Apache spark project

Tags: github, apache-spark

I I am trying to find a source code of OpenHashMapBasedStateMap which is used in the link given below. However I couldn't find the implementation anywhere in the spark repository. What could be the reason for this and how can I look at the source code of that Scala class

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.0/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/util/StateMap.scala

Comment: is it defined on line 84 of the linked file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just in the `StateMap.scala`:

> ```
> /** Implementation of StateMap based on Spark's [[org.apache.spark.util.collection.OpenHashMap]] */
> private[streaming] class OpenHashMapBasedStateMap[K, S](
>     @transient @volatile var parentStateMap: StateMap[K, S],
>     private var initialCapacity: Int = DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY,
>     private var deltaChainThreshold: Int = DELTA_CHAIN_LENGTH_THRESHOLD
>   )(implicit private var keyClassTag: ClassTag[K], private var stateClassTag: ClassTag[S])
> extends StateMap[K, S] with KryoSerializable {
>   ...
> }
> ```

Till now(Aug. 23) it's from line 84

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Thanks very much for the reply.